# How to merge 2 datasets according to DATE

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I am trying to do the following. I have a dataset1 that goes from 2015-01-31 up until 2021-06-30:

```
dataset1_dates=c("2015-01-31","2015-02-28","2015-03-31","2015-04-30","2015-05-31","2015-06-30","2015-07-31","2015-08-31","2015-09-30","2015-10-31","2015-11-30","2015-12-31","2016-01-31","2016-02-29","2016-03-31","2016-04-30","2016-05-31","2016-06-30","2016-07-31","2016-08-31","2016-09-30","2016-10-31","2016-11-30","2016-12-31","2017-01-31","2017-02-28","2017-03-31","2017-04-30","2017-05-31","2017-06-30","2017-07-31","2017-08-31","2017-09-30","2017-10-31","2017-11-30","2017-12-31","2018-01-31","2018-02-28","2018-03-31","2018-04-30","2018-05-31","2018-06-30","2018-07-31","2018-08-31","2018-09-30","2018-10-31","2018-11-30","2018-12-31","2019-01-31","2019-02-28","2019-03-31","2019-04-30","2019-05-31","2019-06-30","2019-07-31","2019-08-31","2019-09-30","2019-10-31","2019-11-30","2019-12-31","2020-01-31","2020-02-29","2020-03-31","2020-04-30","2020-05-31","2020-06-30","2020-07-31","2020-08-31","2020-09-30","2020-10-31","2020-11-30","2020-12-31","2021-01-31","2021-02-28","2021-03-31","2021-04-30","2021-05-31","2021-06-30")
# add dates
dataset1 <- expand.grid(Organisation = c("A123","B234","C456"),
                       Date = dataset1_dates)
  
## sort
dataset1 <- dataset1[order(dataset1$Organisation, dataset1$Date),]
## reset id
rownames(dataset1) <- NULL

dataset1$Organisation <- as.character(dataset1$Organisation)
dataset1$Date <- as.Date(dataset1$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then I have a dataset2 that tells me at specific points in time the performance of each organisation at the time of inspection:

```
dataset2 <- read.table(
  text = "
Organisation    Date_inspection     Performance
A123            2015-01-31          Good
A123            2016-01-14          OK
B234            2017-06-14          Inadequate
C456            2015-06-30          OK
C456            2016-02-10          Inspected but not rated
C456            2018-05-18          Good
C456            2020-03-21          OK",
  header = TRUE)

dataset2$Organisation <- as.character(dataset2$Organisation)
dataset2$Date_inspection <- as.Date(dataset2$Date_inspection, format="%Y-%m-%d")
dataset2$Performance <- as.character(dataset2$Performance)
```

I would like to assign to each month *before* inspection, including the month of the inspection, the performance category of the organisation.

I would also like to consider months after the last inspection as equal to the performance category at date of last inspection.

When 'Inspected but not rated' then assume next category. E.g. for C456 then assume 'Good'.

Expected result:

```
Date        |   Organisation    |     Performance     |
2015-01-31  |   A123            |     Good            |
2015-02-28  |   A123            |     OK              |
2015-03-31  |   A123            |     OK              |
...
2016-01-31  |   A123            |     OK              |
...
2021-06-30  |   A123            |     OK              |
2015-01-31  |   B234            |     Inadequate      |
2015-02-28  |   B234            |     Inadequate      |
2015-03-31  |   B234            |     Inadequate      |
...
2021-06-30  |   B234            |     Inadequate      |
2015-01-31  |   C456            |     OK              |
2015-02-28  |   C456            |     OK              |
2015-03-31  |   C456            |     OK              |
...
2015-06-30  |   C456            |     OK              |
...
2016-02-29  |   C456            |     Good            |
...
2018-05-31  |   C456            |     Good            |
2018-06-30  |   C456            |     OK              |
...
2020-03-31  |   C456            |     OK              |
...
2021-06-30  |   C456            |     OK              |
```

Any ideas on how to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Corrected a mistake. Forgot to group the data.

**Edit2:** Missed the handling for "Inspected but not rated". Thank you @hello_friend!

I think you can handle this with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataset1 %>% 
  mutate(year_month = format(Date, "%Y-%m")) %>% 
  left_join(
    dataset2 %>% 
      mutate(year_month = format(Date_inspection, "%Y-%m"),
             Performance = na_if(Performance, "Inspected but not rated")), 
    by = c("Organisation", "year_month")
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Organisation) %>% 
  fill(Performance, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  select(-year_month, -Date_inspection) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

this returns

```r
# A tibble: 234 x 3
    Organisation Date       Performance
    <chr>        <date>     <chr>      
  1 A123         2015-01-31 Good       
  2 A123         2015-02-28 OK         
  3 A123         2015-03-31 OK         
  4 A123         2015-04-30 OK         
  5 A123         2015-05-31 OK         
  6 A123         2015-06-30 OK         
  7 A123         2015-07-31 OK         
  8 A123         2015-08-31 OK         
  9 A123         2015-09-30 OK         
 10 A123         2015-10-31 OK         
 11 A123         2015-11-30 OK         
 12 A123         2015-12-31 OK         
 13 A123         2016-01-31 OK         
 14 A123         2016-02-29 OK         
 15 A123         2016-03-31 OK         
 16 A123         2016-04-30 OK         
 17 A123         2016-05-31 OK         
 18 A123         2016-06-30 OK         
 19 A123         2016-07-31 OK         
 20 A123         2016-08-31 OK         
 21 A123         2016-09-30 OK         
 22 A123         2016-10-31 OK         
 23 A123         2016-11-30 OK         
 24 A123         2016-12-31 OK         
 25 A123         2017-01-31 OK         
 26 A123         2017-02-28 OK         
 27 A123         2017-03-31 OK         
 28 A123         2017-04-30 OK         
 29 A123         2017-05-31 OK         
 30 A123         2017-06-30 OK         
 31 A123         2017-07-31 OK         
 32 A123         2017-08-31 OK         
 33 A123         2017-09-30 OK         
 34 A123         2017-10-31 OK         
 35 A123         2017-11-30 OK         
 36 A123         2017-12-31 OK         
 37 A123         2018-01-31 OK         
 38 A123         2018-02-28 OK         
 39 A123         2018-03-31 OK         
 40 A123         2018-04-30 OK         
 41 A123         2018-05-31 OK         
 42 A123         2018-06-30 OK         
 43 A123         2018-07-31 OK         
 44 A123         2018-08-31 OK         
 45 A123         2018-09-30 OK         
 46 A123         2018-10-31 OK         
 47 A123         2018-11-30 OK         
 48 A123         2018-12-31 OK         
 49 A123         2019-01-31 OK         
 50 A123         2019-02-28 OK         
 51 A123         2019-03-31 OK         
 52 A123         2019-04-30 OK         
 53 A123         2019-05-31 OK         
 54 A123         2019-06-30 OK         
 55 A123         2019-07-31 OK         
 56 A123         2019-08-31 OK         
 57 A123         2019-09-30 OK         
 58 A123         2019-10-31 OK         
 59 A123         2019-11-30 OK         
 60 A123         2019-12-31 OK         
 61 A123         2020-01-31 OK         
 62 A123         2020-02-29 OK         
 63 A123         2020-03-31 OK         
 64 A123         2020-04-30 OK         
 65 A123         2020-05-31 OK         
 66 A123         2020-06-30 OK         
 67 A123         2020-07-31 OK         
 68 A123         2020-08-31 OK         
 69 A123         2020-09-30 OK         
 70 A123         2020-10-31 OK         
 71 A123         2020-11-30 OK         
 72 A123         2020-12-31 OK         
 73 A123         2021-01-31 OK         
 74 A123         2021-02-28 OK         
 75 A123         2021-03-31 OK         
 76 A123         2021-04-30 OK         
 77 A123         2021-05-31 OK         
 78 A123         2021-06-30 OK         
 79 B234         2015-01-31 Inadequate 
 80 B234         2015-02-28 Inadequate 
 81 B234         2015-03-31 Inadequate 
 82 B234         2015-04-30 Inadequate 
 83 B234         2015-05-31 Inadequate 
 84 B234         2015-06-30 Inadequate 
 85 B234         2015-07-31 Inadequate 
 86 B234         2015-08-31 Inadequate 
 87 B234         2015-09-30 Inadequate 
 88 B234         2015-10-31 Inadequate 
 89 B234         2015-11-30 Inadequate 
 90 B234         2015-12-31 Inadequate 
 91 B234         2016-01-31 Inadequate 
 92 B234         2016-02-29 Inadequate 
 93 B234         2016-03-31 Inadequate 
 94 B234         2016-04-30 Inadequate 
 95 B234         2016-05-31 Inadequate 
 96 B234         2016-06-30 Inadequate 
 97 B234         2016-07-31 Inadequate 
 98 B234         2016-08-31 Inadequate 
 99 B234         2016-09-30 Inadequate 
100 B234         2016-10-31 Inadequate 
101 B234         2016-11-30 Inadequate 
102 B234         2016-12-31 Inadequate 
103 B234         2017-01-31 Inadequate 
104 B234         2017-02-28 Inadequate 
105 B234         2017-03-31 Inadequate 
106 B234         2017-04-30 Inadequate 
107 B234         2017-05-31 Inadequate 
108 B234         2017-06-30 Inadequate 
109 B234         2017-07-31 Inadequate 
110 B234         2017-08-31 Inadequate 
111 B234         2017-09-30 Inadequate 
112 B234         2017-10-31 Inadequate 
113 B234         2017-11-30 Inadequate 
114 B234         2017-12-31 Inadequate 
115 B234         2018-01-31 Inadequate 
116 B234         2018-02-28 Inadequate 
117 B234         2018-03-31 Inadequate 
118 B234         2018-04-30 Inadequate 
119 B234         2018-05-31 Inadequate 
120 B234         2018-06-30 Inadequate 
121 B234         2018-07-31 Inadequate 
122 B234         2018-08-31 Inadequate 
123 B234         2018-09-30 Inadequate 
124 B234         2018-10-31 Inadequate 
125 B234         2018-11-30 Inadequate 
126 B234         2018-12-31 Inadequate 
127 B234         2019-01-31 Inadequate 
128 B234         2019-02-28 Inadequate 
129 B234         2019-03-31 Inadequate 
130 B234         2019-04-30 Inadequate 
131 B234         2019-05-31 Inadequate 
132 B234         2019-06-30 Inadequate 
133 B234         2019-07-31 Inadequate 
134 B234         2019-08-31 Inadequate 
135 B234         2019-09-30 Inadequate 
136 B234         2019-10-31 Inadequate 
137 B234         2019-11-30 Inadequate 
138 B234         2019-12-31 Inadequate 
139 B234         2020-01-31 Inadequate 
140 B234         2020-02-29 Inadequate 
141 B234         2020-03-31 Inadequate 
142 B234         2020-04-30 Inadequate 
143 B234         2020-05-31 Inadequate 
144 B234         2020-06-30 Inadequate 
145 B234         2020-07-31 Inadequate 
146 B234         2020-08-31 Inadequate 
147 B234         2020-09-30 Inadequate 
148 B234         2020-10-31 Inadequate 
149 B234         2020-11-30 Inadequate 
150 B234         2020-12-31 Inadequate 
151 B234         2021-01-31 Inadequate 
152 B234         2021-02-28 Inadequate 
153 B234         2021-03-31 Inadequate 
154 B234         2021-04-30 Inadequate 
155 B234         2021-05-31 Inadequate 
156 B234         2021-06-30 Inadequate 
157 C456         2015-01-31 OK         
158 C456         2015-02-28 OK         
159 C456         2015-03-31 OK         
160 C456         2015-04-30 OK         
161 C456         2015-05-31 OK         
162 C456         2015-06-30 OK         
163 C456         2015-07-31 Good       
164 C456         2015-08-31 Good       
165 C456         2015-09-30 Good       
166 C456         2015-10-31 Good       
167 C456         2015-11-30 Good       
168 C456         2015-12-31 Good       
169 C456         2016-01-31 Good       
170 C456         2016-02-29 Good       
171 C456         2016-03-31 Good       
172 C456         2016-04-30 Good       
173 C456         2016-05-31 Good       
174 C456         2016-06-30 Good       
175 C456         2016-07-31 Good       
176 C456         2016-08-31 Good       
177 C456         2016-09-30 Good       
178 C456         2016-10-31 Good       
179 C456         2016-11-30 Good       
180 C456         2016-12-31 Good       
181 C456         2017-01-31 Good       
182 C456         2017-02-28 Good       
183 C456         2017-03-31 Good       
184 C456         2017-04-30 Good       
185 C456         2017-05-31 Good       
186 C456         2017-06-30 Good       
187 C456         2017-07-31 Good       
188 C456         2017-08-31 Good       
189 C456         2017-09-30 Good       
190 C456         2017-10-31 Good       
191 C456         2017-11-30 Good       
192 C456         2017-12-31 Good       
193 C456         2018-01-31 Good       
194 C456         2018-02-28 Good       
195 C456         2018-03-31 Good       
196 C456         2018-04-30 Good       
197 C456         2018-05-31 Good       
198 C456         2018-06-30 OK         
199 C456         2018-07-31 OK         
200 C456         2018-08-31 OK         
201 C456         2018-09-30 OK         
202 C456         2018-10-31 OK         
203 C456         2018-11-30 OK         
204 C456         2018-12-31 OK         
205 C456         2019-01-31 OK         
206 C456         2019-02-28 OK         
207 C456         2019-03-31 OK         
208 C456         2019-04-30 OK         
209 C456         2019-05-31 OK         
210 C456         2019-06-30 OK         
211 C456         2019-07-31 OK         
212 C456         2019-08-31 OK         
213 C456         2019-09-30 OK         
214 C456         2019-10-31 OK         
215 C456         2019-11-30 OK         
216 C456         2019-12-31 OK         
217 C456         2020-01-31 OK         
218 C456         2020-02-29 OK         
219 C456         2020-03-31 OK         
220 C456         2020-04-30 OK         
221 C456         2020-05-31 OK         
222 C456         2020-06-30 OK         
223 C456         2020-07-31 OK         
224 C456         2020-08-31 OK         
225 C456         2020-09-30 OK         
226 C456         2020-10-31 OK         
227 C456         2020-11-30 OK         
228 C456         2020-12-31 OK         
229 C456         2021-01-31 OK         
230 C456         2021-02-28 OK         
231 C456         2021-03-31 OK         
232 C456         2021-04-30 OK         
233 C456         2021-05-31 OK         
234 C456         2021-06-30 OK
```

##Data
Here are the data after all those transforming shown in the question.

```r
dataset1 <- structure(list(Organisation = c("A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", "A123", 
"A123", "A123", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", "B234", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456", "C456"), Date = structure(c(16466, 
16494, 16525, 16555, 16586, 16616, 16647, 16678, 16708, 16739, 
16769, 16800, 16831, 16860, 16891, 16921, 16952, 16982, 17013, 
17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 17166, 17197, 17225, 17256, 17286, 
17317, 17347, 17378, 17409, 17439, 17470, 17500, 17531, 17562, 
17590, 17621, 17651, 17682, 17712, 17743, 17774, 17804, 17835, 
17865, 17896, 17927, 17955, 17986, 18016, 18047, 18077, 18108, 
18139, 18169, 18200, 18230, 18261, 18292, 18321, 18352, 18382, 
18413, 18443, 18474, 18505, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18627, 18658, 
18686, 18717, 18747, 18778, 18808, 16466, 16494, 16525, 16555, 
16586, 16616, 16647, 16678, 16708, 16739, 16769, 16800, 16831, 
16860, 16891, 16921, 16952, 16982, 17013, 17044, 17074, 17105, 
17135, 17166, 17197, 17225, 17256, 17286, 17317, 17347, 17378, 
17409, 17439, 17470, 17500, 17531, 17562, 17590, 17621, 17651, 
17682, 17712, 17743, 17774, 17804, 17835, 17865, 17896, 17927, 
17955, 17986, 18016, 18047, 18077, 18108, 18139, 18169, 18200, 
18230, 18261, 18292, 18321, 18352, 18382, 18413, 18443, 18474, 
18505, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18627, 18658, 18686, 18717, 18747, 
18778, 18808, 16466, 16494, 16525, 16555, 16586, 16616, 16647, 
16678, 16708, 16739, 16769, 16800, 16831, 16860, 16891, 16921, 
16952, 16982, 17013, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 17166, 17197, 
17225, 17256, 17286, 17317, 17347, 17378, 17409, 17439, 17470, 
17500, 17531, 17562, 17590, 17621, 17651, 17682, 17712, 17743, 
17774, 17804, 17835, 17865, 17896, 17927, 17955, 17986, 18016, 
18047, 18077, 18108, 18139, 18169, 18200, 18230, 18261, 18292, 
18321, 18352, 18382, 18413, 18443, 18474, 18505, 18535, 18566, 
18596, 18627, 18658, 18686, 18717, 18747, 18778, 18808), class = "Date")), out.attrs = list(
    dim = c(Organisation = 3L, Date = 78L), dimnames = list(Organisation = c("Organisation=A123", 
    "Organisation=B234", "Organisation=C456"), Date = c("Date=2015-01-31", 
    "Date=2015-02-28", "Date=2015-03-31", "Date=2015-04-30", 
    "Date=2015-05-31", "Date=2015-06-30", "Date=2015-07-31", 
    "Date=2015-08-31", "Date=2015-09-30", "Date=2015-10-31", 
    "Date=2015-11-30", "Date=2015-12-31", "Date=2016-01-31", 
    "Date=2016-02-29", "Date=2016-03-31", "Date=2016-04-30", 
    "Date=2016-05-31", "Date=2016-06-30", "Date=2016-07-31", 
    "Date=2016-08-31", "Date=2016-09-30", "Date=2016-10-31", 
    "Date=2016-11-30", "Date=2016-12-31", "Date=2017-01-31", 
    "Date=2017-02-28", "Date=2017-03-31", "Date=2017-04-30", 
    "Date=2017-05-31", "Date=2017-06-30", "Date=2017-07-31", 
    "Date=2017-08-31", "Date=2017-09-30", "Date=2017-10-31", 
    "Date=2017-11-30", "Date=2017-12-31", "Date=2018-01-31", 
    "Date=2018-02-28", "Date=2018-03-31", "Date=2018-04-30", 
    "Date=2018-05-31", "Date=2018-06-30", "Date=2018-07-31", 
    "Date=2018-08-31", "Date=2018-09-30", "Date=2018-10-31", 
    "Date=2018-11-30", "Date=2018-12-31", "Date=2019-01-31", 
    "Date=2019-02-28", "Date=2019-03-31", "Date=2019-04-30", 
    "Date=2019-05-31", "Date=2019-06-30", "Date=2019-07-31", 
    "Date=2019-08-31", "Date=2019-09-30", "Date=2019-10-31", 
    "Date=2019-11-30", "Date=2019-12-31", "Date=2020-01-31", 
    "Date=2020-02-29", "Date=2020-03-31", "Date=2020-04-30", 
    "Date=2020-05-31", "Date=2020-06-30", "Date=2020-07-31", 
    "Date=2020-08-31", "Date=2020-09-30", "Date=2020-10-31", 
    "Date=2020-11-30", "Date=2020-12-31", "Date=2021-01-31", 
    "Date=2021-02-28", "Date=2021-03-31", "Date=2021-04-30", 
    "Date=2021-05-31", "Date=2021-06-30"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-234L), class = "data.frame")

dataset2 <- structure(list(Organisation = c("A123", "A123", "B234", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456"), Date_inspection = structure(c(16466, 
16814, 17331, 16616, 16841, 17669, 18342), class = "Date"), Performance = c("Good", 
"OK", "Inadequate", "OK", "Inspected but not rated", "Good", 
"OK")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: great simple solution. You forgot to recode in your mutate though, as follows:   `mutate(
        year_month = format(Date_inspection, "%Y-%m"),
        Performance = recode(
          Performance,
          "Inspected but not rated" = NA_character_
          )
        )`

Comment: @hello_friend You're right, i missed that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this can be simplified but will work as desired:

```
# Recode Inspected but not rated to an NA of type 
# character: clean_df2 => data.frame
clean_df2 <- transform(
  with(
    dataset2, 
    dataset2[
      rev(
        order(
          Date_inspection
        )
      ),
    ]
  ),
  Performance = gsub(
    "Inspected but not rated",
    NA_character_,
    Performance
  )
)


# Expand the "dataset2" to months which the ratings
# are considered applicable over: 
# inspectionsApplicable => data.frame
inspectionsApplicable <- unique(
  data.frame(
    do.call(
      rbind, 
      lapply(
        with(
          clean_df2,
          split(
            clean_df2, 
            Organisation
          )
        ),
        function(x){
          x$Month_inspected <- as.Date(
            strftime(
              x$Date_inspection,
              "%Y-%m-01"
            )
          )
          MaxMonthInData <- as.Date(
            strftime(
              max(
                dataset1$Date[
                  dataset1$Organisation == 
                  unique(x$Organisation)
                ]
              ), 
              "%Y-%m-01"
            )
          )
          data.frame(
            Organisation = c(
              x$Organisation[1],
              x$Organisation
            ),
            Months = c(
              as.Date(MaxMonthInData),
              as.Date(x$Month_inspected, "%Y-%m-%d")
            ),
            Performance = c(
              x$Performance[
                which.min(
                  cumsum(
                    !(
                      is.na(
                        x$Performance
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              ],
              x$Performance
            )
          )
        }
      )
    ),
    row.names = NULL
  )
)

# Left join the tables, dropping dupes from 
# from inspection result data.frame: ir_res => data.frame
ir_res <- merge(
  transform(
    with(
      dataset1,
      dataset1[
        rev(
          order(
            Organisation, 
            Date
          )
        ),
      ]
    ), 
    Months = as.Date(
      strftime(
        Date,
        "%Y-%m-01"
      )
    )
  ),
  with(
    inspectionsApplicable,
    inspectionsApplicable[
      !(
        duplicated(
          paste0(
            Organisation, 
            Months
          ),
          fromLast = TRUE
        )
      ),
    ]
  ),
  by = c(
    "Organisation",
    "Months"
  ),
  all.x = TRUE
)

# Back fill by group: res_ir2 => data.frame
res_ir2 <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(
    with(
      ir_res,
      split(
        ir_res,
        Organisation
      )
    ),
    function(x){
      y <- with(
        x,
        x[
          rev(
            order(
              Date
            )
          ),
        ]
      )
      transform(
        y, 
        Performance = na.omit(
          Performance
        )[
            cumsum(
              !(
                is.na(
                  Performance
                  )
                )
              )
            ]
      )
    }
  )
)

# Order by date and organisation: res => data.frame
res <- data.frame(
  with(
    res_ir2, 
    res_ir2[
      order(
        Organisation,
        Date
      ),
    ]
  ),
  row.names = NULL
)
```

Comment: Thanks @hello_friend - had to accept the first solution since it was the first posted, but appreciate all your input!